# how to change the Application Api level from 2.1 to 2.2

Tags: android, upgrade

I have completed the application in 2.1 and now I have phone with android 2.2.  What do I need to do in order to rebuild the application in 2.2?

Comment: your application may already work in android 2.2, are you currently restricting the SDK version in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are using eclipse then it is very simple
in project explorer
click on

```
Project->properties->android->select target
```

and then build your project

also u need to change api level of menifest file

Comment: if you are using any other then plz notify me